# How can you share an audience from Google Analytics to Facebok remarketing

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, remarketing

Can you use the audience lists that you created in Analytics, in Facebook or you should create them straight in Facebook?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with Google Analytics audience, so I found the documentation: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2611404?hl=en.  It looks like you create an audience to use with remarketing ads, correct?   So you want to use the audience with Facebook remarketing ads?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the same audience from Analytics to retarget people in Facebook. I know I can create the audience(website visitors) in Facebook but there is no use if you can use the one from Analytics.